# Angular Using Random Url For Requests

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, proxy

I'm trying to create a proxy for my angular application and my post request keeps getting sent to

> http://www.gamersunite.com/users

even though i'm trying to post to

> http://localhost:3000/api/users

At one point I had my proxy set as

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://url.com",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""}
  }
}
```

but now it's currently

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

Why is it still redirecting to this random url?

Comment: have you cleared your cache (turned it off in developer mode)? checked any uses of cookies/sessions that may use URLs?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Sure enough that did it.

Answer (score 0):

Cleared the cache/cookies and now everything is working as expected